# Why am I unable to connect using Remote Desktop on my Windows 10 computer?

Tags: networking, windows-10, remote-desktop

I have two computers that came with Windows 8.1. I recently upgraded them to Windows 10. I've been trying to configure the machines for remote access but am having limited/no luck.

The RDP connection fails when specifying either the hostname or the IP of the target machine.

I have tried the following to attempt to solve the issue:

- Checked that the target PC has Remote Desktop enabled. The `Allow this computer to be controlled remotely` checkbox under `This PC` -> `Properties` -> `Remote Settings` -> `Advanced` is indeed checked.
- Disabled Windows Firewall in case this is causing connection issues.
- Use a wired, rather than wireless, connection.
- Verified that both machines could ping each other successfully (they could).
- Verified that Remote Desktop is attempting to listen on port 3389 by checking the registry value at `Computer\HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-TCP\PortNumber` (this value is indeed correct). As it turns out, Remote Desktop is actually NOT listening on this port (or apparently any port). I was able to find this information by running `netstat -a | findstr 3389`.
- Toggling the Remote Desktop checkbox (see above) and then restarting, per a suggestion I found using Google. I tried this in various ways, including:
- Disabling Remote Desktop and then restarting. Then enabling Remote Desktop and then restarting.
- Disabling Remote Desktop, then enabling it, then restarting.

  None of these cause Remote Desktop to start listening on this port.
- Putting the two computers in a homegroup together, per another suggestion. After doing this, the two computers share files and other resources.

**How can I fix this issue with Remote Desktop and allow the target machine to be connected to remotely?**

As you can see, I've tried a lot of things to solve this issue. Hopefully I've missed something that somebody can spot!

Comment: Have you tried RDPing both with the IP and Hostname?

Comment: Yes. I failed to indicate this, but this was part of my earlier attempts to connect to this other machine.

Comment: What edition of Windows 10 do you have? Is this home? Home Edition has only remote desktop client and you cannot connect via RDP to it.

Comment: @Volodymyr I'll review this. Now that i think about it, i didn't know that Home Edition didn't allow remote connections...I think it would be nice if MS did disable a feature, the UI selections to enable/disable it would have some indicator of this besides simply not actually toggling the functionality...

Comment: Any update on your issue @Beta033? It sounds just like what I'm running into, except IDK if it is Home Edition (yet).

Comment: Do you have port forwarding set up on your router?

Comment: Home edition does not have the "Allow this computer to be controlled remotely ..." check box.. It only shows the the check box that allows remote assistance requests.

Comment: Have you tried launching the Remote Desktop application from a command line (or the Run dialog) like this `mstsc /admin`? Just curious..

Comment: If your Windows was 8.1, then your Windows 10 is home edition. While if your Windows 8.1 Pro, then your Windows 10 is Pro. You can check that from right-click on This PC icon, choose properties. you'll find either Windows 10 or Windows 10 Pro. The Windows 10 home edition doesn't have the Remote Desktop feature , you will have to add it manually by a third party tool called RDPWrap..

Comment: For me using the Host Name will fail in finding the remote computer, but specifying the IP address worked.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Did you add your user to the remote user list]

Did you add your user to the remote user list?

> This PC -> Properties -> Remote Settings -> Advanced -> Select Users ... And select the users.

Also, Did you allow the incoming connections on port 3389 TCP?

> Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Advanced settings -> Inbound Rules -> New Rule ... And follow the wizard to add the port.

[How to add a rule or port to a Windows 10 firewall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AcqibSJ8ng)

Comment: How does one add the user to the remote user list in specific detail?

Comment: @Ramhound ? What do you mean? With an administrative account you just go to computer properties, remote access, select users, and add As the pictures shows.

Comment: I personally know how to do it.  Your answer does not explain how to do it.  The author might not know how to do it.  Anyone with this same question as the author, is not likely to know, how to do it themselves.

Comment: Right, there is more information now ;)

Comment: The lower box with the "select users" button is not present on my Remote tab... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can telnet the PC to check whether RDP port is opened.

Telnet tserv

It should make communication and get a response.

Source - https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/187628/using-telnet-to-test-port-3389-functionality

Also, a few points to consider.
1) Network Level Authentication
2) Firewall settings or personal firewall and AV settings - that might block incoming RDP requests.
3) User/Group permission
4) Check the remote desktop service

More detailed information available here in [fixing RDP issues in Windows 10.](https://www.sysprobs.com/connect-remote-desktop-windows-7-fix)

Comment: Why would telnet help, especially without specifying the RDP port?