# Windows 10 can not connect via RDP to any other Windows

Tags: networking, windows-10, remote-desktop

"Remote Desktop Connection" doesn't seem to work with Windows-10.
It can't connect to my local network computers and virtual machines. I used to have it in Windows-7.

**A screenshot of error message when I try to establish RDP connection:[image]**

**Fact**
I'm running a Windows-7 virtualmachine, and with this OS I can establish RDP connection to any other OS in my local network Windows or Linux doesn't matter. This clearly means nothing is wrong with other machines or network but Windows-10 itself.

What happened to "Remote Desktop Connection" tool how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Just for the record, there is nothing wrong with Windows 10 and Remote Desktop per se. I use it all the time both for incoming and outgoing rdp and it works fine. If you are connecting *to* a Windows 10 machine are you sure it is a 'Professional' version? Windows Home versions don't allow Remote Desktop incoming connections (but you can connect from them as client) - this is standard Windows behaviour, not new to Windows 10.

Comment: Windows 10 Pro is host. Other computers are XP Professional, Windows 7 Ultimate and Ubuntu based Linux distributions.

Comment: either the Windows 10 host is configured not to allow rdp connections (see answer 1 below), or there is a firewall issue, I suspect

Comment: I'm not trying to connect to Windows-10. Windows-10 is the computer I will use to connect other computers as this makes the below answer useless.

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/957494/windows-10-rdp-does-not-connect-to-remote-computer?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the system properties on the other PC's?

[image: System Properties]

Comment: This situation has nothing to do with other computers. A Windows-7 virtualmachine able to connect other computers. Other computers are fine. Problem itself is Windows-10 at the moment.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is then.

Comment: You say you're using Win-10 but then you say "Fact I'm running a Windows-7 virtualmachine"

Comment: For the test purposes to prove other computers are fine, Windows 7 as a virtual machine able to connect. It's a comparison.