# Strange.. can't connect to 2012 R2 from only one of my Windows 10 Boxes?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, connection, windows-10

I have a very strange situation on my home network and I just can't figure out the issue. My home network consists of a cable modem, DD-WRT router, switch, server box, pc box, laptop, phones and tablets.

Yesterday, a windows update was pushed to the laptop (which runs Win10 x64). I believe it was the rather large cumulative update that was released recently.

Afterwards, using the laptop, I could not connect to my Windows 2012 R2 server, although I could ping it. Doing the typical IT troubleshooting thing, I tried several different 'tests' to try and diagnose the problem:

- I cannot RDP to the server from the laptop - just says it can't communicate with the remote machine.
- I cannot view any web sites (eg PLEX) that run on the server from the laptop. Just says it cannot connect.
- I can successfully ping the server from the laptop.
- My PC, which runs Win10 and is connected via LAN, can RDP and view sites on the server.
- The laptop is connected via wifi. I can connect to the server web sites (eg PLEX) from my phone/tablet, which are also connected via wifi.
- I can connect to other internally hosted sites (eg my NAS, printer) from the laptop.
- I tried disabling anti-virus, malwarebytes and the firewall on the laptop.
- I made sure that on the laptop, windows update was updated, and the latest drivers for the wifi driver / chipset.
- I tried connected to the server where the laptop network connection was set to both 'public' and then 'private'.
- Obviously, I rebooted the router, the laptop, the server.
- Other than the failure to connect to the server, the laptop is running perfectly fine - does everything that it used to.

I would consider myself fairly good with IT but this has got me stumped. Does anyone have any further tests I could try? Or better yet, some diagnostics I could run? Or even better, has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Did you tested wired ?

Comment: No I haven't. I considered that and thought I would rule that out by being able to connect via other wifi devices.. but I will test that tonight.

Comment: I sometimes find that a windows update, the machine behaves strangely until I complete a reboot.

Comment: similar thread with no apparent answer, but maybe some ideas; http://superuser.com/q/957494/258947

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue, maybe try [this article](http://www.guidingtech.com/51111/guide-remote-desktop-windows-10/)

Comment: @CAB hopeful.. but I can RDP fine to the server from another machine - I'm trying with the exact same username & pwd.. also I thought it was firewall, but like i said - I can connect without any issues from another machine on the LAN. And I tried disabling the firewall on the laptop, that didn't help. :(

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the latest update is not recommended, even though, try to uninstall the large cumulative update and try to connect your laptop.

Please follow the below steps:-

Open - CMD with admin privileges - type wmic qfe.   This command will show the list of updates.  Select that update which may be the root cause of issue and uninstall it.

The same steps can be performed in Windows Update in control panel.